# VirtualBox - convert a list of virtual machine files into 1 file

Tags: virtualbox

I have a virtual machine in VirtualBox. The machine is composed of multiples files like:
- machine.vbox
- machine-disk1-s001.vmdk
- ...

I which to distribute the machine by having only 1 file. The user download the file, open it with virtualbox and enjoy.

Is there a way to do this with virtualbox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edu is correct, but I'll go into a little more detail.  There are two built-in ways to export a VM with VirtualBox and then a roundabout way.

#### The Hard Way

The roundabout way would be to just compress the directory holding all the VM files into a zip file or a tarball.  (Zip files are generally more compressed, but not every machine has zip functionality built in.  Most of them can untar things without installing something new.  Your choice.)  You'll then need to use VBox's command line API to get VirtualBox to import and register the new VM.  (See the [VirtualBox Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html) sections on import and register, 8.10 and 8.6, respectively.)

#### The Easy Ways

The two built-in ways are described in the [VirtualBox Manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf) (an indispensable reference if you expect to do more things like this).  The two built-in ways are basically the same, except one will give you a set of files representing the VM and the other way will give you a single file representing the VM.

To use either built-in way:

1. Go to the VirtualBox Manager window and go to File > Export Appliance...
2. In the window that pops up, choose which VM you want to export and click "next."
3. In the textbox labeled "File:" choose both the location and a name for the VM you're exporting.
4. **Before** clicking "next," choose a file extension for your export file.
5. If you type ".ovf" as your file extension, you will have *several files* in one directory, all of which together are the VM you're exporting.
6. If you type ".ova" as your file extension, you will have *one* file which is the VM you're exporting.

From here all you have to do is get your exported VM file(s) to the physical machine you want this VM on.  Start VirtualBox running, go to File > Import Appliance... and browse to where your exported VM file(s) is(are).  VirtualBox will configure everything for you.

#### Importing to Machines Not Running VirtualBox

If the physical machine you want to run this VM on uses virtualization software other than VirtualBox, you're not hosed so long as you used one of the built-in ways.  (Zipping or tar'ing won't work for this.)

If you saved your exported VM as a .ova file, use tar to uncompress the file into a handful of files.  VirtualBox has specifically set up .ova to be used with tar.  (I think at this point they're exactly the same as if you had exported a .ovf instead.)

If you exported them as .ovf, then the exported files are already in standardized virtualizer format so several different versions of virtualization software can read it as if you originally created the clone in that non-VirtualBox software.  All you have to do is import it with that virtialization's standard import method.

Comment: Hahaha, yeah, I've been using the advanced command line features for a few months now and only recently noticed that they had a nice easy way to export VMs.  (There's a command line equivalent to the GUI way too.)  The learning never stops.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can export it as an appliance.which others can import easily. The drawback is that snapshots are not exported with the machine.

If you want move everything connected to machine, just copy the whole directory. You can zip it to one file if needed. Receiver would then just copy the directory to their Virtualbox directory and select "Add" to add it to their inventory.